# Flutter ListView.builder with Wrap widget

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following code and i want the items displayed horizontally but it is displaying them vertically. anybody have an idea what am i doing wrong?

```
                      ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: _categories.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (_, i) => Wrap(
                            direction: Axis.horizontal,
                            spacing: 10.0,
                            runSpacing: 20.0,
                            children: [
                              CategoryItem(
                                _categories[i].id,
                                _categories[i].name,
                                _categories[i].description,
                                _categories[i].imageUrl,
                                _categories[i].restaurantId,
                              ),
                              Divider(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to change `Scroll Direction` from `Vertical` to `Horizontal` like below. Currently you are setting it `Vertical` so that is causing the issues change your code as below.

```
    ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _categories.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (_, i) => Wrap(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        spacing: 10.0,
        runSpacing: 20.0,
        children: [
        CategoryItem(
            _categories[i].id,
            _categories[i].name,
            _categories[i].description,
            _categories[i].imageUrl,
            _categories[i].restaurantId,
            ),
            Divider(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `scrollDirection` of the `ListView` to `horizontal` by doing this :

`scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`.

Check the code below, it works well.

```
      ListView.builder(
                          // set the scrollDirection here 
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,  
                          itemCount: _categories.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (_, i) => Wrap(
                            direction: Axis.horizontal,
                            spacing: 10.0,
                            runSpacing: 20.0,
                            children: [
                              CategoryItem(
                                _categories[i].id,
                                _categories[i].name,
                                _categories[i].description,
                                _categories[i].imageUrl,
                                _categories[i].restaurantId,
                              ),
                              Divider(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

set `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` or remove the `scrollDirection:` property, the default scroll direction is horizontal.